# PHP - Too few arguments to function index()

Tags: php, laravel, function, routes

I'm making an application where I'm trying to show different elements depending on the role, but I get that error in the title.

- In AppointmentController.php:

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAll()
    {
        return Appointment::all();
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($user)
    {
        $appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', '=', $user)->get();
        return $appointments;
    }
}
```

- Api.php:

```
Route::post('appointment/show', [AppointmentController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth:api'); //Role Client.
Route::get('appointment/showAll',[AppointmentController::class,'indexAll'])->middleware('role:admin');  //Role Admin.
```

Comment: `index()` method need parameter and you are not sending it.

Comment: You must type-hint the `$user`, otherwise the DI don't know what to insert for you. So it should be `index(User $user)`

Comment: try using this Route::post('appointment/show/{$user}', [AppointmentController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth:api'); //Role Client.

Comment: Your route should have a route parameter in definition to be available in the controller method `Route::post('appointment/show/{user}', [AppointmentController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth:api');` In you view from where you are making the request you must pass the id of User (if role is client) as route parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index route should have a parameter like this

```
Route::post('appointment/show/{id}', [AppointmentController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth:api'); //Role Client.
```

And then access the route with the real values which exists in database,
for example:

```
appointment/show/1
```